# How to create a sequence number based on database registers with concurrent users

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, jpa, concurrency

All this happens in a java web application, using JPA in the persistence layer.
I have entities A and B. A has many of B.

The user wanted a number to identify Bs, it would help them using the system. We used B's primary key for this purpose. The pk is a simple Oracle sequence.
After some time, the user didn't like the numbers generated. He would like B's numbers to be sequential, but in each instance of A.

Ex:

```
A 1  B1
A 1  B2
A 1  B3
A 2  B1
A 2  B2
```

and so on....

I had in mind this (naive) solution:

-Create a new colunm for the new B's number

-Create a unique clause with B's new number and A's FK.

-When creating a new instance of B, check the database for the last number of B given a instance of A.

-Since more than one user may create a instance of B, when inserting B, do a try catch. If more than one user inserts a B with the same number (for the same A instance), then catch the exception thrown from the database.

-If the exception was thrown, try to insert again with a new number.

The reason for my question is that I find this solution quite clumsy since it relies on the try-catch to do a new insertion when the concurrency problem happens. I believe there is a better way to deal with concurrency in this scenario, but I can't think of another way of solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Transactional
public void createB(informations){

    A a = informations.getA()
    session.get(A.class, a.getId(), LockMode.READ) //BD Lock here, no cluster, no Java

    //Only who got the lock first get here, anyone else waits for the lock release

    Long lastSequential = bService.findLastSequential()
    B newB = informations.getB()
    newB.setSequential(lastSequential + 1)
    session.persist(newB)

    //The lock is released when the transaction finishes and then the next
    //thread awaiting on the session.get may get a new lock and resume its 
    //execution. That way only one thread at time will be able to execute
    //the critical area where the sequential is being created.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with a rather unique situation here, I'd say...

if you really need to do this, try/catch/retry doesn't seem to be a good solution, since depending on the number of concurrent users, a single retry may result again in a DB failure and you'd have to retry again and the cycle goes on.

I guess you could try taking a look at surrogate keys for that. The "lookup tables" approach described here seems to be a good starting point for what you need: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/should-every-table-have-a-single-field-surrogate-artificial-primary-key

There a few other articles/posts about hibernate and surrogate keys: 
- [Hibernate : Opinions in Composite PK vs Surrogate PK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577754/hibernate-opinions-in-composite-pk-vs-surrogate-pk)
- http://richmurnane.blogspot.de/2007/09/hibernate-and-surrogate-keys.html

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The main catch you have the synchronization issue which can be handled many ways.

1. Your sequence of B is dependent on the A id you are giving. So your query would be something like select max(B) from B where B.A = ?.
2. Now let's say you got B10. Put the value of A on some collection, may be a map with A and max value of B. Use synchronization for getting/ adding a value from this map.
3. Whenever you want a new A-B combination in the map, first check whether it is there. If there, wait and retry again after specified time to ensure you have the updated record.
4. From point 2, after getting B10 as current, increment and insert B11 for corresponding A and delete the map entry, so the next thread will query and get B11 for that A.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an option to use another column rather than PK, you could look at using a List with an `@OrderColumn` annotation which:

> maintains a contiguous (non-sparse) ordering of the values of the
>   order column

While zero based, it does have the advantage of being automatically updated to reflect any insertions, deletions etc.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html